# why is pygame not opening audio file? is it because I am using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, pygame, python-3.6

Edit: I've got it to run however, I cannot hear audio.

`import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("alarmsound.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()`

Comment: You might want to check the return value of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
# load sound file
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)

pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("bird.ogg")
snd_array = pygame.sndarray.array(sound)
snd_out = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(snd_array)
snd_out.play()
```

Comment: It says unable to "Unable to open file 'alarmsound.wav'"

Comment: put the correct path of audio file into pygame.mixer.Sound and will works ( my example - bird.ogg sound file is in the same folder with the script )

Answer (score 0):

To run `pygame.mixer.music.play()`, you need to input two values: the number of times it plays, and when to play it.
For example:
`pygame.mixer.music.play(1,0.0)` would play the sound one time upon running the program. For infinite loops, use -1. If you want more information, I suggest going to the pygame docs at: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("alarmsound.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play((# of times),(when you want it to play))
```